Why I cannot call function and an initialized variable the same?
#include <iostream>
double towerHeight()
{
    std::cout << "Insert the height of the tower";
    double towerHeight{};
    std::cin >> towerHeight;
    return towerHeight;
}


int main()
{
    double towerHeight {towerHeight()};
}

When in main, if I try to initialize the value towerHeight with the function towerHeight(), I have an error.., but if I call my function owerHeight or something different, the problem disappears... why can't I call variable and function, the same?
I tried to change the name of the function and it works.

double towerHeight {::towerHeight()}; - you use the same name for both and if you do double towerHeight {towerHeight()}; the second one will mean the one in the immediate scope, that is, the double variable

Regardless of whether you can work around it, having the same name for two different things is a really really bad idea.

Always post complete error along with your question. Also a good c++ book

C Local variable has same name as function - how does it work?

When you wrote double towerHeight {towerHeight()};, you redeclared towerHeight to be a variable name of type double. And we can't call a variable of type double. This is why the error says: towerHeight' cannot be used as a function


why can't I call variable and function, the same?

When you wrote double towerHeight {towerHeight()};  you've redeclared towerHeight to be a variable instead of a function. That is, the moment double towerHeight is parsed, the name towerHeight is now a variable name in the scope of the main function. And since a variable of type double can't be called like towerHeight(), we get the error saying exactly this:
error: 'towerHeight' cannot be used as a function
   13 |      double towerHeight {towerHeight()};
      |                          ~~~~~~~~~~~^~

Workaround
There are multiple workaround for this. You can just change the name of the variable or the function. Other is to just use scope resolution operator :: as shown below:
//------------------vv--------------->this means you want to use the global function named towerHeight
double towerHeight {::towerHeight()};


The other answer already explains why exactly it is not possible to have a variable and a function with the same name at the same scope.
Note that is it generally not a good idea anyway to give the same name to 2 different things.
If you insist on doing so, you can do it by using the :: prefix with the function name. This will tell the compiler to use it from the global scope:
int main()
{
//----------------------VV---------------
    double towerHeight{ ::towerHeight() };
    std::cout << towerHeight << std::endl;
}

Some more info about using the :: prefix can be found here: When to use "::" for global scope in C++?.
